# Webpack complains of a typescript definition file import - unless I add a `d.ts` ending

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have the weirdest situation where my webpack build complains of *a single instance* of importing a file where it cannot find the file, unless I add a `.d.ts` or `.d` ending in the the import literal.

```
ERROR in ./src/screens/homeward-questionnaire-schedule/HomewardQuestionnaireScheduleScreen.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../types/schedule-type-interfaces' in '/home/myuser/dev/nicecorp/nicecorp-frontend/src/screens/homeward-questionnaire-schedule'
 @ ./src/screens/homeward-questionnaire-schedule/HomewardQuestionnaireScheduleScreen.tsx 33:0-66 380:10-20 384:10-20 388:10-20 392:10-20 396:10-20 400:10-20 404:10-20 408:10-20 412:10-20 416:10-20
 @ ./src/components/one-offs/MainGuiLayout.tsx
 @ ./src/components/one-offs/AppWrapper.jsx
```

The file is imported in 3 files, and it is only an issue in this single file:

```
$ git grep schedule-type-interfaces
src/screens/homeward-questionnaire-schedule/HomewardQuestionnaireScheduleScreen.tsx:import { ButtonProp, Question, QuestionId } from '../../types/schedule-type-interfaces'
src/screens/homeward-questionnaire-schedule/QuestionSelector.tsx:import { Question } from '../../types/schedule-type-interfaces'
src/utils/questionnaire-util.ts:import { ButtonProp, Question } from '../types/schedule-type-interfaces'
```

Adding this single diff will make the build pass with flying colors:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/nicecorp-frontend/src/screens/homeward-questionnaire-schedule/HomewardQuestionnaireScheduleScreen.tsx b/nicecorp-frontend/src/screens/homeward-questionnaire-schedule/HomewardQuestionnaireScheduleScreen.tsx
index 0a2a3e366..4d3def526 100644
--- a/nicecorp-frontend/src/screens/homeward-questionnaire-schedule/HomewardQuestionnaireScheduleScreen.tsx
+++ b/nicecorp-frontend/src/screens/homeward-questionnaire-schedule/HomewardQuestionnaireScheduleScreen.tsx
@@ -32,7 +32,7 @@ import { Encounter, Patient, QuestionnaireSchedule } from '../../types/domain-ty
 import { CancellationCriteriaEnum } from '../../types/enums'
 import { nicecorpError } from '../../types/other-types'
 // TODO: find out why we need the extension for webpack not to fail
+import { ButtonProp, Question, QuestionId } from '../../types/schedule-type-interfaces.d'
-import { ButtonProp, Question, QuestionId } from '../../types/schedule-type-interfaces'
 import { connectWithDataLoader } from '../../utils/composer'
 import {
   dayNameMap,
```

This makes no sense to any of us, so I am reaching out in hope of becoming smarter. So it can find the file no problem if skipping the `*.ts` ending, but I have to specify `*.d.ts` for it to not fail. So weird. This is the directory in which the file lives - no name clashes:

```
$ ls -1 src/types/
base-type-interfaces.d.ts
base-types.js
completable-types.js
domain-type-interfaces.d.ts
domain-types.js
dom-types.js
enums.js
other-type-interfaces.d.ts
other-types.js
questions-types.js
react-specific-types.js
README.md
schedule-type-interfaces.d.ts
```

Comment: Show us the content of the file that triggers the error. It's quite possible that you're using an `import` from that module in a manner that necessitates it have an implementation but you have no `.js` corresponding to it. Adding the `.d` is definitely wrong. You really don't want to do that.

Comment: That was actually right on the money, and you can see this by looking at the file listing! This file name was created by someone else. This is actually not a correct use for a `*.d.ts` file, because there is no accompanying `*.js` file! I renamed all the offending `*.d.ts` files to `*.ts` and presto, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`*.d.ts` files are supposed to add typings for existing javascript code. We simply used them for creating interfaces, for some weird historical reasons, and people forgot why in the process, creating new ones.

Renaming these files to `*.ts` was what fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm glad you got everything working. Just a slight correction. `.d.ts` files only need an accompanying implementation if they export declared values, i.e. `const` or `class` or `function` etc. However it is best to stick to `.ts`/`.tsx` files as you suggest regardless.

Comment: Yeah, and it has worked for the most part, up until this peculiar situation. No idea what made it different, but sticking with the most standard convention fixed it.

Comment: If you are curious to know why it failed, you can look at `HomewardQuestionnaireScheduleScreen.tsx` and see how the imports from `base-type-interfaces` are used. If any of them are used in value position, it would fail.

Comment: They were only used as types in interface declarations. I don't see how renaming the file they were declared in from `*.d.ts` to `*.ts` should matter at all, really, since there were no other changes needed to make the compiler stop complaining, so I put this one in the "compiler quirks" category.